# Form placement in a div

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, verify

I tried to create a form that covers almost all of the content of my page. Since the input field is scattered, it verifies but still proceeds to the next page afterwards. I don't know what the problem is; it works fine in HTML and PHP formats when I try it offline. The problem happens when I upload it to the server.

The script:

```
<form method="post" action="step.php" id="form1">
<div id="content">
<center>
<br><br><br>
      <input  id="sig" name="sig" type="text" class="validate[sign] text-input" style="margin-left:-180px;visibility:hidden;height:0px;"/>


    <div id="signatureparent">
    <div id="signature"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</center>

<!====================================================================================>




<div id="content">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="form-div">
<center><strong>Please enter the information for the person who will be the primary contact for our account set up team. If left blank we will use the information in the billing section.</strong></center>
<div id="wrapper3">
<div id="form-div">

<center>
<table cellpadding='0' cellspacing='27'>
<tr>
<td>
<!====================================================================================>
<div style="display:none">
<label for="name"><strong>First Name<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="name">
         <input name="name" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="validate[custom[name]] text-input" id="Name" value="<?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>" />

      </p>
<label for="last" style="margin-left:45px;"><strong>Last Name<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="last">
         <input name="last" style="margin-left:45px;" readonly="readonly" type="text" class="validate[custom[last]] text-input" id="last" value="<?php echo $_POST["last"]; ?>" />

      </p>
</div>

<!====================================================================================>
<label for="cname"><strong>First Name<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="cname">
         <input name="cname" type="text" class="validate[custom[cname]] text-input" id="cname" value="" />
        </p>

<label for="cemail"><strong>E-mail<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="cemail">
        <input name="cemail" type="text" class="validate[custom[cemail]] text-input" id="cemail" value=""  />

      </p>

<!====================================================================================>
</td><td>

<label for="clast" style="margin-left:45px;"><strong>Last Name<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="clast">
         <input name="clast" style="margin-left:45px;"  type="text" class="validate[custom[clast]] text-input" id="clast" value="" />

      </p>

<label for="cphone" style="margin-left:45px;"><strong>Phone<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="cphone">
        <input type="text" class="validate[custom[mob]] text-input" name="cphone" id="cphone"  style="margin-left:45px;width:100px" /> 

 <b>ext</b><input style="width:25px; margin-left:5px;" type="text" class="validate[custom[ext]] text-input" name="cext1" id="cext1" />
        </p>

</td><td>


<!====================================================================================>   
<label for="ccom" style="margin-left:45px;"><strong>Company<font color=red size=3> *</font></strong></label>
      <p class="com">
        <input type="text" class="validate[custom[ccom]] text-input"name="ccom" id="ccom" onblur="this.value = this.value.toTitleCase();" style="margin-left:45px;" />
      </p>

<label for="cmob" style="margin-left:45px;"><strong>Mobile#</strong></label>
      <p class="mob">
        <input type="text" class="validate[custom[mob]] text-input" name="cmob" id="cmob" style="margin-left:45px;width:100px;" /> 


<b>ext</b><input style="width:25px; margin-left:5px;" type="text" class="validate[custom[ext]] text-input" name="cext2" id="cext2" />
        </p>

</div></div></div></div></div>
</center>
</td></tr></table>

<div>

<!====================================================================================>
<br>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="form-div">

<table><tr><td><div style="margin-left:210px;" >
<p><font color=red size=2%><b>Clicking this button means that you accept the terms and conditions of our service  </b></font></td><td>
<div id="accept"><button style="margin-left:10px;border: 0; background: transparent" type="submit"><img src=img/acept.png height=30 /></button>
 </div>
</tr></td></table>
</div>
</div>  
<br><br><br>

</form>
```

It should first verify the contents, then proceed.

Comment: now none of that makes any sense

Comment: i know right? no sense at all

Comment: i roughly remember the original question, so it makes a little sense, but it wont' to someone just coming to it for the first time

Comment: deleted the content got down voted for unknown reason ?

Comment: perhaps post the code itself. External links like that tend to tick some people off, post any errors if you got them (client or server side)

Comment: want to post it but it will require a huge amount of x4 Spacebar the whole page there is no error by the way, it's just the form gets submitted even without content

Comment: @Link — The edit window has a toolbar! You don't need to indent manually!

Comment: didnt notice just new here so i dont know all of the fx

Comment: what sort of validation are you talking about? client side as in javascript, or serverside, or both? maybe start with that. What about a small(er) form for test purposes only. Do that just to get process right.

Comment: so where's the validation logic? or am i missing something?

Comment: the logic is fine on other pages

Comment: @Link - It appears that the form has no onsubmit tag; it wouldn't run the validate code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your form does not run any code on submitting it. You'd want your form to have:

```
<form method="post" action="step.php" id="form1" onsubmit="return validate()">
```

This is assuming that your validation code is as a JavaScript function.